# How to get the texture and color of a peeled and cross section of banana? Something like in the photo

Tags: texture-painting

I want to create a composition of banana, I have made one with it's peel but having difficulty in giving texture and the color to the the cylindrical cross section. [image]

Comment: The best way is to take a picture of a real cross section and use that as a texture.

Comment: But to add to that, use that texture of the cross section in both the main one and on a boolean obejct so that it shows up when you 'cut' the banana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Painted a slice and a tube]
This is a slice made to be slightly larger than the tube, two different materials.
[image: Second step]
tube has UV maps for smart unwrap for the sides and end and project from view for the straight end projection
[image: scale on y]
Scaled up the slice on the y axis to prepare to use as booltool cutter
[image: bool]
Set a booltool difference and then an error shows, to fix I swapped UV maps in the main tube image material
[image: final]